# SDL2_ttf Subpixel Antialiasing

Tags: c++, sdl-2, antialiasing, sdl-ttf

Is it possible to render text with the SDL2 library using a [subpixel rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering) technique to increase the quality on LCD screens?  (Preferably with standard SDL2_ttf.)

The following image demonstrates precisely what I'm aiming for, where the image on the far-left is the actual result that would be seen upon zooming in:

[image: subpixel rendering example]

If this is not possible 'out of the box', but you believe it *is possible to implement* in the open-source SDL2_ttf; I'd appreciate some ideas or pointers in the right direction as to how it could be implemented.

---

#### EDIT:

I've started looking through the [source code of SDL2_ttf](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/), and came to the conclusion that it I would have to modify it in order to achieve subpixel LCD antialiasing.
From what I've researched about FreeType, I would have to change the following lines of code:

```
// (from SDL_ttf.c, approx. line 650)
/* Render the glyph */
error = FT_Render_Glyph(glyph, mono ? ft_render_mode_mono : ft_render_mode_normal);
```

To

```
/* Render the glyph, (ft_render_mode_mono is also deprecated) */
error = FT_Render_Glyph(glyph, mono ? FT_RENDER_MODE_MONO : FT_RENDER_MODE_LCD);
```

Additionally, some code needs to be added to write to the bitmap. I have absolutely no idea how to do this, as I barely understand what's already there, due to the lack of comments. The following is the 'grey 2-bit' pixel-mode's code:

```
// (from SDL_ttf.c, approx. line 800)
// ... other pixel modes handled above this...
else if (src->pixel_mode == FT_PIXEL_MODE_GRAY2) {
    // srcp appears to be the source buffer, 
    // and dstp the destination buffer.
    unsigned char *srcp = src->buffer + soffset;
    unsigned char *dstp = dst->buffer + doffset;
    unsigned char c;
    unsigned int j, k;

    // No idea how any of this works.
    // I'd guess 'j' should increment by 1
    // instead of 4, since LCD uses 8-bits.
    for (j = 0; j < src->width; j += 4) {
        c = *srcp++;
        for (k = 0; k < 4; ++k) 
        {
            // Literally no idea where they pulled these numbers out.
            if ((c&0xA0) >> 6) {
                *dstp++ = NUM_GRAYS * ((c&0xA0) >> 6) / 3 - 1;
            } 
            else {
                *dstp++ = 0x00;
            }
        }
        c <<= 2;
    }
}
// 4-bit grey is done down here...
```

I'm hoping someone is capable of helping me out on this one...
Cheers.

Comment: I wouldn't reinvent the wheel. 1. Find a library that supports subpixel rendering and if you really need to use SDL2 images, then 2. Find a way to convert back and forth from SDL2 images and library X images, which shouldn't be too hard. Great album btw.

Comment: @nada

Thanks for the advice. I will take that into consideration. 
Though the main reason why I asked is because SDL2_ttf uses the FreeType library (which appears to support subpixel rendering.) So I was wondering if there were any flags or something that I could set to enable this.
And yeah Rumours is awesome :D

Answer (score 0):

The best SDL2_ttf can do is grayscale anti-aliasing in the [Shaded and Blended](https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/docs/SDL_ttf.html#SEC42) modes.

To get sub-pixel rendering you'll have to [drop back to FreeType](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-lcd_rendering.html).

A new hinter setting `TTF_HINTING_LIGHT_SUBPIXEL` introduced in [a recent HG commit](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL_ttf/rev/9f46efc0fde2) looks like it will give you grayscale subpixel positioning (it maps down to [FreeType's `FT_LOAD_TARGET_LIGHT`](https://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#ft_load_target_xxx)).

Comment: Thank you for the information. (Including the hinter setting, despite being somewhat irrelevant to my question.)
Do you think it's possible to modify the SDL2_ttf source code to enable FreeType's subpixel antialiasing? Or should I take @nada 's advice and find an additional library?

Comment: I'm trying to compile that HG repository you linked, ([from this commit](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL_ttf/archive/55e20cb392b4.tar.gz)) But I am struggling to get it to compile. According to the link you posted, a SDL2 version with the `SDL_MEMALIGNED` flag set is required, though I have no idea where to retrieve a build with this flag. I tried building SDL2 from source, but couldn't find the flag anywhere in the code.

Comment: @Michael: Looks like the `SDL_MEMALIGNED` surface flag was added in ["Add SDL_MEMALIGNED flag for SDL_Surface using aligned memory."](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/b2d4dcb4ba33) and renamed to `SDL_SIMD_ALIGNED` a few days later in ["Rename surface aligned memory flag to SDL_SIMD_ALIGNED"](https://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/rev/85bc5436a005).

Comment: Okay compiling that bleeding-edge version of SDL allowed me to use subpixel text hinting, which improved the clarity of text by a great amount, so thanks for that. Still haven't found a way to get subpixel _antialiasing_ though...